# How to count how many consonants are in a string?

Tags: javascript

Am I somewhere near the solution? I always get a double number of the consonants.

I was convinced that this was the correct approach.

```js
function consonants(str) {
  var countConsonants = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {

    if (str[i] !== "a" || str[i] !== "e" || str[i] !== "i" ||
      str[i] !== "o" || str[i] !== "u" || str[i] !== " ") {
      countConsonants += 1;
    }
  }
  return (countConsonants);
}
consonants("asdfghaaa");
```

I am expecting an answer of 5 i.e. `sdfgh` are the consonants.

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty close. You want to loop `i < str.length`, not `<=`.

Comment: use && operator instead of ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in counts lies within your conditions.

You're increasing the number of consonants whenever one of the conditions fail (that's what `||` does, known as the OR operator). So whenever a character `!== "a"` OR `!== "e"`, you're increasing the count, which is wrong. (Imagine that a is `!== 'e'`, so you're counting a as a consonant).

Change the `||` binary operator to `&&` (AND); this way, you're only increasing the consonant count whenever the current character `str[i]` is not among the values you're verifying for (a, e, i, o, u, ' ').

As others pointed out, you're also likely to run into an error as the max value of i should be Length-1.

There also other problems you need to consider:

- What happens when the character is an uppercase letter?
- What happens when the character is a punctuation mark or a number?

For a beginner, this may not be relevant, but it's well worth getting these techniques under your skin: It's more readable to create an array that contains all of the value you're verifying for ["a","e", etc] and then, for each char in the source string, just verify if array.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0 (which means that the character is included in the array).

Comment: A binary operator is defined as an operator that takes two operands; not binary in the sense of the binary number system ?

Comment: Yeah seems right. I've always called bitwise operators binary operators but it seems this is incorrect

Comment: thank you very much! Just the amount of details I needed!

Answer (score 6):

Your logic is flawed, The operator in your condition should be AND `&&` not OR `||`, since you want to compare all the chars not just one of them :

```js
function consonants(str) {
  var countConsonants = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if (str[i] !== "a" && str[i] !== "e" && str[i] !== "i" &&
      str[i] !== "o" && str[i] !== "u" && str[i] !== " ") {
      countConsonants++;
    }
  }
  return (countConsonants);
}
console.log(consonants("asdfghaaa"));
```

**NOTE :** The loop should stop at `length-1` since arrays are 0 based, so replace :

```
for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
__________________^^
```

By :

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
__________________^
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```js
let str = 'asdfghaaa';

let result = str.split('').filter(e => e.match(/[^aeiou]/) != null).length;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is returning the count of vowles not consonants. The answer should be 5 not 4.

Comment: And it somehow also counts full stops, question marks and company

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is almost right. The only problem is `||` instead of `&&`. You're checking that it's not a AND it's not e AND it's not i, etc. Your function comes out true for every letter, since a is (not a || not e), right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to and your conditions because if you use `||` the condition always evaluates to true. Your loop should go from 0 to index < str.length.

```js
function consonants(str) {
 var countConsonants = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str.charAt(i) !== "a" && str.charAt(i) !== "e" && str.charAt(i) !== "i" 
   && str.charAt(i) !== "o" && str.charAt(i) !== "u" && str.charAt(i) !== " ") {
   countConsonants++;
  }
  }
    return countConsonants;
}
console.log(consonants("asdfghaaa"));
```

Comment: explain why && is required

Answer (score 1):

```
function consonants (str) {
    return str.match(/[aeoiu]/gi)||[].length;
}
```

May be not good for long string.

Answer (score 0):

I had this challenge too here is how i did:

```js
const paragraph = "A quick brow fox is trying to bite me."
paragraph.match(/(?![aeiou])[a-z]/gi, "").length
```

Source: https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/regex-for-consonants/282833/4

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example

```js
  let str="Hello world.";
  let vowel=str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
  let consonant = str.match(/[^aeiou .]/gi).length;
  console.log("Vowel "+vowel+"\n");
  console.log("Vowel "+consonant+"\n");
```